# why __dependent_type from libcxx uses a template non-type parameter bool _Dummy?

Tags: c++, templates, libc++

Here is the definition of __dependent_type:

```
template <class _Tp, bool>
struct _LIBCPP_TEMPLATE_VIS __dependent_type : public _Tp {};
```

All use cases:

```
/usr/.../c++/v1 >>> rg "_dependent_type"                                                                                                                      
memory
2211:          __dependent_type<is_default_constructible<_T1>, _Dummy>::value &&
2212:          __dependent_type<is_default_constructible<_T2>, _Dummy>::value
2402:      typename __dependent_type<_DeleterSFINAE, _Dummy>::__lval_ref_type;
2406:      typename __dependent_type<_DeleterSFINAE, _Dummy>::__good_rval_ref_type;
2410:      typename __dependent_type<_DeleterSFINAE, _Dummy>::__bad_rval_ref_type;
2412:  template <bool _Dummy, class _Deleter = typename __dependent_type<
2671:      typename __dependent_type<_DeleterSFINAE, _Dummy>::__lval_ref_type;
2675:      typename __dependent_type<_DeleterSFINAE, _Dummy>::__good_rval_ref_type;
2679:      typename __dependent_type<_DeleterSFINAE, _Dummy>::__bad_rval_ref_type;
2681:  template <bool _Dummy, class _Deleter = typename __dependent_type<

variant
1134:            enable_if_t<__dependent_type<is_default_constructible<__first_type>,
1292:              __dependent_type<is_move_constructible<_Types>, _Dummy>::value &&
1293:              __dependent_type<is_swappable<_Types>, _Dummy>::value)...>::value,

tuple
621:            __lazy_all<__dependent_type<is_default_constructible<_Tp>, _Dummy>...>
```

### Question:

Isn't

```
template <class _Tp>
struct _LIBCPP_TEMPLATE_VIS __dependent_type : public _Tp {};
```

and

```
 __dependent_type<is_default_constructible<_T1>>::value
```

enough?

Why does libcxx need this dummy bool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the dummy `bool` that makes the type dependent, this is the whole point of `__dependent_type`, otherwise you can just use the type itself.

Take this code as example:

```
  template <bool _Dummy>
  using _GoodRValRefType =
      typename __dependent_type<_DeleterSFINAE, _Dummy>::__good_rval_ref_type;
```

Without the dummy to make it a dependent type, when the class template gets instantiated, `_DeleterSFINAE::__good_rval_ref_type` might cause a hard error, because not all of the `_DeleterSFINAE` has a `__good_rval_ref_type` member.

The dependent type delays evaluation, so that you can use `_GoodRValRefType` in a SFINAE context later.