# How does the implementation of range-v3's meta::defer work?

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming, deferred-execution, range-v3

Here is the implementation of `meta::defer`:

```
template <template <typename...> class C, typename... Ts>
struct defer : detail::defer_<C, Ts...> {};
```

`detail::defer_`

```
template <template <typename...> class C, typename... Ts>
using defer_ = decltype(detail::try_defer_<C, Ts...>(0));
```

`detail::try_defer`

```
    template <template <typename...> class C, typename... Ts,
              template <typename...> class D = C>
    id<D<Ts...>> try_defer_(int);
    template <template <typename...> class C, typename... Ts> nil_ try_defer_(long);
```

`struct id`

```
    template <typename T> struct id {
    #if defined(__GNUC__) && !defined(__clang__) && __GNUC__ < 5 &&                \
        !defined(META_DOXYGEN_INVOKED)
      // Redirect through decltype for compilers that have not
      // yet implemented CWG 1558:
      // <http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1558>
      static id impl(void *);

      template <typename... Ts>
      using invoke = _t<decltype(id::impl(static_cast<list<Ts...> *>(nullptr)))>;
    #else
      template <typename...> using invoke = T;
    #endif

      using type = T;
    };
```

`struct nil_ {};`

[official doc(example use case)](https://ericniebler.github.io/meta/structmeta_1_1defer.html)

> A wrapper that defers the instantiation of a template C with type parameters Ts in a lambda or let expression.
>
> In the code below, the lambda would ideally be written as lambda<_a,_b,push_back<_a,_b>>, however this fails since push_back expects its first argument to be a list, not a placeholder. Instead, we express it using defer as follows:
>
> ```
> template<typename List>
> using reverse = reverse_fold<List, list<>, lambda<_a, _b, defer<push_back, _a, _b>>>;
> ```

According to the use case, `meta::defer` seems to defer the expression until SFINAE work. But I cannot figure out how does the implementation work.

### Question

### 1. How does `meta::defer` work?

### 2. libcxx also has a `struct __dependent_type`, whose definition is:

```
template <class _Tp, bool>
struct _LIBCPP_TEMPLATE_VIS __dependent_type : public _Tp {};
```

and [I also ask a question about `__dependent_type`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53901072/why-dependent-type-from-libcxx-uses-a-template-non-type-parameter-bool-dummy)(to avoid repetitions, I don't put details of `__dependent_type` here)

If `meta::defer` is just to defer the expression for SFINAE, is it possible to replace it with `__dependent_type` above, and why?

Comment: "Here is the implementation of meta::defer" - Are you sure? Following your "official doc" link, and corresponding "meta.hpp", I see `defer` inherits from `detail::defer_<C, list<Ts...>>`. And other differences.

Comment: @max66 I guess in doc, `list` is just for more readable. In source code, the details are as I list. You can see this commit, whichis found from git blame: https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3/commit/304b5664dcb2044b9ab7a7df9862a0314480e614#diff-305c0246765a6a57be4e5ab4664dbc96R49

Comment: @max66 this is more clear: https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3/pull/643/commits/3e3a766d92dced759559064e2ba741f150171ca3